# SQL Server 2014 SP2, backup and restore with powershell

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, backup

I have a task where i have to take the backup with encryption and restore it to destination using the powershell.

I used the invoke-sql command and use the tsql in it but this command is not reliable for us rather we want to use the SQL powershell i.e backup-sqldatabase & restore sqldatabase.

my questions are what are the process to perform it (please i dont want to use invoke-sqlcmd)

- create master using powershell ( i use "create master key encryption
  by password = 'Abcd1234!'" in invoke-sqlcommand)
- Create certificate using powershell
- backup-certificate
- create backup using encryption

Answer (score 2):

You can use [dbatools](https://dbatools.io/download/) which is powershell based.

For your case you need to have a 2 step approach.

1. use the cmdlets in Backup and Restore – Certificates

> Backup-DbaDbCertificate
>
> Backup-DbaDbMasterKey
>
> Restore-DbaDbCertificate

then use [`Copy-DbaDatabase`](https://docs.dbatools.io/#Copy-DbaDatabase) with `-BackupRestore` switch. Alternately, you can use `Backup-DbaDatabase` and then `Restore-DbaDatabase` as per your needs.

Comment: i dont think, i can install that module due to limitation at work..but sqlps & sqlserver powershell modules are available

Comment: Then the only option that you have is to code something that is already out by your self

Comment: Those modules (SQLPS and SQLSERVER) do *not* come with cmdlets that covers the full spectra of T-SQL commands. Very very far from it. You have backup-sqldatabase and a few others. But in the end you only have a handful of cmdlets in those modules. So if you want to use something which is outside of the cmdlets, then use a 3:rd party (dbatools), Invoke-Sqlcmd or the SMO API (from powershell since ps allow using .Net assemblies).